# Regular Expression in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I need create a regular expression for validate the first and second name of a person. The second name is optional because there are people without second name. The space character can be between the two names, but it can not be the end of string

```
example

 "Juan Perez" is valid
 "Juan Perez " is invalid because there is a space character the end of the string
```

Comment: It's true that there are people without second names (the best-known being "Cher"), but they are quite few in number, so I don't think you need worry about them. Wiki gives this [List of legally mononymous people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_legally_mononymous_people). The one I like best is "KentuckyFriedCruelty.com".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the below regex which uses an optional group.

```
^[A-Za-z]+(?:\s[A-Za-z]+)?$
```

`(?:\s[A-Za-z]+)?` optional group will do a match if there is a space followed by one or more alphabets. It won't match the string if there is only a single space exists. And also it asserts that there must be an alphabet present at the last.

[DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/4BegVPS6M4)

**Update:**

If the user name contains not only the  firstname but also middlename,lastname ... then you could use the below regex. `*` repeats the previous token zero or more times where `?` after a token (*not of `*` or `+`*) will turn the previous token as an optional one.

```
^[A-Za-z]+(?:\s[A-Za-z]+)*$
```

Comment: thanks Avinash Raj. How can I apply this regular expression if I don't know the number the names that a person has?. These can be 1,2,3 or four

Comment: just turn the last `?` to `*`

Comment: You should probably use `[[:alpha:]]` rather than `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: Whenever I see a Ruby regex question I am reminded of a famous line from the movie [Field of Dreams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_Dreams), but it's Avinash who will soon appear (not Shoeless Joe Jackson).

Answer (score 1):

How about a way that doesn't require repeating the char class:

```
^\b(\s?[[:alpha:]]+)+$
```